# Please help me understand this proof...

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let's say a lake has $4$ types of fish. What is the number of possible outcomes (number of each type of fish caught) if a total of $10$ fish are caught?

We'd use the formula and find the answer like $^{10+4-1}C_{4-1} = {^{13}C_3}$. But the book explains how this result is obtained. I do understand Proposition $6.1$ but I don't get the highlighted paragraph (Proposition $6.2$)... please see:

[image]

[image]

Comment: By the way, what book is this?

Answer (score 0):

By proposition 6.1, there are $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ distinct positive integer solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^r x_i=n$.

Then there are $\binom{n-1+r}{r-1}$ distinct positive integer solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^r y_i=n+r$.

So by sustracting $r$ from left and right, and setting $x_i=y_i-1$, we have that there are $\binom{n-1+r}{r-1}$ non-negative integer solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^r x_i=n$.   (Non-negative integers because if $y_i\in\Bbb Z^+$ then $y_i-1\in \Bbb Z^+\cup\{0\}$ )

Comment: I dont understand this.. the new equation.. why did he add 1 to the x's.. and how will its solution give the non-negative possibilities??

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{f_{1} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{f_{2} = 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{f_{3} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{f_{4} = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{z^{10}}z^{f_{1} + f_{2} + f_{3} + f_{4}} & =
\bracks{z^{10}}\pars{\sum_{f = 0}^{\infty}z^{f}}^{4} =
\bracks{z^{10}}\pars{1 - z}^{-4} = {-4 \choose 10}\pars{-1}^{10}
\\[5mm] & =
{13 \choose 10}\pars{-1}^{10} = {13 \times 12 \times 11 \over 3 \times 2} = \bbx{286}
\end{align}